# Saved sublime, and now I can't connect to localhost:3000 on OS X 10.9.5

Tags: syntax-error, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm new to programming and I have this problem that I can't find an answer for - I've saved an update in sublime and haven't been able to connect to http://localhost:3000 (on OS X 10.9.5)

I keep getting a syntax error when I try to restart the server or migrate the database:
config/routes.rb:63: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)

Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments, only: [:create]
      end

```
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created ->            highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id:    product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a syntax error in routes.rb.  Maybe you should edit the contents of that file into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the initial declaration of the routes file. See the example below. You are getting this error because at the bottom of the file there is an `end` and it does not know what you're trying to end.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #Routes Go Here
end
```